# What is wrong in saveRDS

Tags: r, save

I want to automate saving data objects with code:

```
files <- c("df1", "df2", "df3", ...)
path <- "~/location"

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  saveRDS(files[i], file = paste0(path, "/", files[i], ".Rds"))
}
```

df1, df2, df3, ... are object names, but it writes just data object names in files not the data.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: using `saveRDS(df1, file = paste0(path, "/", "df1", ".Rds"))` writes data as expected

Comment: Your vector of files is a `character` -vector. `saveRDS` requires a DF-object.

Comment: You can use `get(files[i])`.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent `saveRDS(get(files[i]), file = paste0(path, "/", files[i], ".Rds"))` does it as expected